# Unable to use textbox ID's in code behind

Tags: asp.net

I am having a grid with columns which have textboxes and I have want to restrict Backspace and Delete key when pressed inside the textbox. I'm using this script to do that. And in code behind, in page load event when I try to refer the grid columns textbox's ID, they are not showing up. I am using textbox inside itemtemplate and the textbox is made read-only.

Javascript:

```
function doCheck()
    {         
        var keyCode = (event.which)?event.which:event.keyCode;
        if ((keyCode == 8) || (keyCode == 46))
            event.returnValue = false;         
    }
```

page_load event:

```
 txtCode.Attributes.Add("onKeyDown", "doCheck();");
```

I 'm not able to refer any of the grid's textbox ID's. Am I going wrong somewhere?

Comment: What if someone uses the "cut" functionality to remove the text?

Comment: Haven't thought of that. Believe this is more sufficient!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try below code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        TextBox txtCode = (TextBox) e.Row.FindControl("txtCode");
        txtCode.Attributes.Add("onKeyDown", "doCheck();");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**you need to bind that event to each and every row of the grid by using RowDataBound Event:**

```
  protected void RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                e.Row.cells[Index].Attributes.Add("onkeyDown", "function");
            }
        }
```

**Where Index is the column index which is containing your textbox**

Hope this helps..